# Progress Bars Don't Animate

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a list of progress bars which I would like to see animate. I see them animate when I use the maxcdn but not if I use local bootstrap references. Please help me understand what wrong...

```css
.resume {
    width: 816px;
    margin: 48px 48px 48px 48px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
}
.header {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 4px;
}
.header hr {
    margin: 5px;
}
.name {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 32px;
}
.contact p {
    margin: 10px;
}
.summary h2, .skills h2, .professionalhistory h2, .education h2 {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.skills {
    line-height: 13px;
}
.skills p {
    margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
.progress {
    background-color: #BCBEBF;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 13px;
    margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
.progress-bar {
    background-color: #323232;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 13px;
    padding: 1px 10px 2px;
}
.progress-bar span {
    padding: 1px 10px 2px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    color: white;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translate(0%,-50%);
}
.employer {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.position {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.description {
    width: 95%; 
    margin-left: 12px;
}
.results {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.titles {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <p>Microsoft Office SharePoint Services</p>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:53.85%">
      <span>7 Years</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

In the snippet I am using the maxcdn but if I remove the maxcdn the progress bars still display but don't animate. I am not sure why. Boot version is 4.0.0 alpha 6.

Comment: bootstrap.min.css V3.3.7 must not be compatible with bootstrap 4

Comment: It's because your local version is Bootstrap 4 alpha, which requires an additional class for animation. The CDN you are using is for Bootstrap 3, which does not require that additional class for an animated progress bar. See answer below.

Comment: Thank you @APAD1

Comment: You are quite welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In Bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/progress/) you need to add the class `progress-bar-animated` to the `progress-bar` element.

```css
.resume {
    width: 816px;
    margin: 48px 48px 48px 48px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
}
.header {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 4px;
}
.header hr {
    margin: 5px;
}
.name {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 32px;
}
.contact p {
    margin: 10px;
}
.summary h2, .skills h2, .professionalhistory h2, .education h2 {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.skills {
    line-height: 13px;
}
.skills p {
    margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
.progress {
    background-color: #BCBEBF;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 13px;
    margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
.progress-bar {
    background-color: #323232;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 13px;
    padding: 1px 10px 2px;
}
.progress-bar span {
    padding: 1px 10px 2px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    color: white;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translate(0%,-50%);
}
.employer {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.position {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.description {
    width: 95%; 
    margin-left: 12px;
}
.results {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.titles {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <p>Microsoft Office SharePoint Services</p>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13"aria-valuemin="0"aria-valuemax="13" style="width:53.85%">
      <span>7 Years</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/a2f6g3gs/

**Add:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var progress = setInterval(function() {
        var $bar = $('.progress-bar');

        if ($bar.width()>=400) {
            clearInterval(progress);
            $('.progress-bar').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $bar.width($bar.width()+40);
        }
        //$bar.text($bar.width()/4 + "%");
    }, 1);
    });
</script>
<style>
    .progress .progress-bar {
        -moz-animation-name: animateBar;
        -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -moz-animation-duration: .4s;

        -webkit-animation-name: animateBar;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -webkit-animation-duration: .4s;

        animation-name: animateBar;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        animation-duration: .4s;
    }

    @-moz-keyframes animateBar {
        0% {-moz-transform: translateX(-100%);}
        100% {-moz-transform: translateX(0);}
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes animateBar {
        0% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);}
        100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0);}
    }
    @keyframes animateBar {
        0% {transform: translateX(-100%);}
        100% {transform: translateX(0);}
    }
</style>
```